# Bicep: azure policy assignment scope

Tags: azure, azure-policy, azure-bicep

I am trying to deploy an **Azure Policy Assignment** with **Bicep**.

```
resource policy_assignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments@2021-06-01' = {
  name: 'my_policy'
  location: 'westus'
  scope: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups',  resourceGroup().name)
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '/subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/mymi': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    parameters: {
      MyParamKey: '/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx/resourcegroups/my-rg2/providers/microsoft.network/virtualnetworks/vnetmy/subnets/default'
    }
    policyDefinitionId: '/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx//providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/my-policy-def'
  }
}
```

When I check it with `az bicep build --file .\policy_assignment.bicep` , I get the error below:

```
C:$Path.bicep(4,10) : Error BCP036: The property "scope" expected a value of type "resource | tenant" but the provided value is of type "string".
C:$Path.bicep(13,32) : Warning BCP036: The property "MyParamKey" expected a value of type "ParameterValuesValue" but the provided value is of type "'/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxx/resourcegroups/my-rg2/providers/microsoft.network/virtualnetworks/vnetmy/subnets/default'".
```

I have two problems:

- Definition of the scope of the policy assignment.
- Definition of the parameter of the assignment

I couldn't find much example on the internet. The documentation of the Policy Assignment for Bicep is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.authorization/policyassignments?tabs=bicep).

Do you have any idea how can I correct these errors?

Comment: Hello @MoonHorse, May I know what is the policy you are trying to assign ? is it Custom or Built -in ?

Comment: For the scope you can just set `scope: resourceGroup()`.

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT, it is a custom policy

Comment: @Thomas, thanks, I don't receive scope error, anymore. I got to fix parameter error now

Comment: what is this `MyParamKey` for ?

Comment: @Thomas It is a parameter asked by the policy definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This resource type most probably expects parameter values to be wrapped in objects with a `value` like :

```
parameters: {
  MyParamKey: {
    value: '/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx/resourcegroups/my-rg2/providers/microsoft.network/virtualnetworks/vnetmy/subnets/default'
  }
}
```

There are [some other use cases](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/1340) like this one.

EDIT : As stated by @Thomas, the scope should be referred as `scope: resourceGroup()` since this is dynamically retrieved by your client with the right type Bicep is waiting for.

Comment: that worked, upvoted it! If you add the 'scope: resourceGroup()' to the answer, I will accept it as the answer for the question.

Comment: Thanks! Edited with a mention to @Thomas' comment :)